# transform a normal website to a responsive website

Tags: css

my question is basic and simple i have a website with normal css code and i want to transform it to a responsive website is there any automatic way to do or generate the good css files , otherwise what could i do to do that.

my css look something like that

```
        #bar1
        {
          border-style:solid;
        border-color:#8c8c8c;
         border-width:1px;
         width:736px;
         height:98px;
         float:right; 
         background-color:white;
          position:absolute;
         top:0px;
         left:212px;

        }
```

Comment: It is not as "basic and simple" as you think.

Comment: My answer is basic and simple ... search about responsive sites, media queries, em units, % percentage, frameworks as bootstrap or foundation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing really "automatic" if you want to do it yourself ...

In a broad sense, you need to replace your fixed pixel values for widths & heights with percentages. 
Also replace fixed font sizes with `em`s, and play with using percentages or ems for padding & margins too.

For example, if you have this:

```
body {
  width: 900px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;    
}
```

Change it to something like:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Now if you resize your browser window the page elements will react & resize. 
Look into the use of media queries & setting breakpoints at different screen widths to change the layout to best fit the current size.

More importantly, figure out if/why you actually need a responsive site.
Where/how might people use it & what info you want to display at different sizes?
Look into "Mobile First" design considerations and create appropriate layouts for the site at different sizes, then figure out how to make the CSS work.

...Or skip all the hard work & put your site into Wordpress or a Bootstrap template that has already done this for you.